# php - Can anyone explain me this line of code?

Tags: php

I can understand the part of ternary operator, still I don't understand the first part where the null is assigned to the $offset variable

```
$offset = null == $offset ? 0 : $offset;
```

Comment: read like `$offset = (null == $offset) ? 0 : $offset;` ,`?`ternary operator and  if condition is true than 0 will be assigned to  `$offset` else `$offest`

Comment: thats weird `$offset` is not defined yet, should be isset

Comment: The comparison operator has higher precedence than assignment, so the comparison (and indeed the whole ternary check) executes before any assignment

Comment: Thanks everyone, if someone add an answer I can accept it

Comment: question is closed as duplicate so its already answered in  base question